# How to Passing A List Of Objects Into An MVC Controller Method Using jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-apicontroller

This is my API Controller. The customfiltervalues are null:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/ajaxapi/customfilters")]
public List<CustomCaseValues> CustomFilters(List<CustomFilterValues> customfiltervalues)
{
```

This is my data:

```
    var customfiltervalues =[
        {
            TableName: $('#tableOneTableName').val(),
            ColumnName: $('#tableOneColumnName').val(),
            Condition: $('#tableOneCondition').val(),
            TextBox: $('#tableOneTextBox').val(),
            Operator: $('#tableOneOperator').val()
        },
        {
            TableName: $('#tableTwoTableName').val(),
            ColumnName: $('#tableTwoColumnName').val(),
            Condition: $('#tableTwoCondition').val(),
            TextBox: $('#tableTwoTextBox').val(),
            Operator: $('#tableTwoOperator').val()
        },
        {
            TableName: $('#tableThreeTableName').val(),
            ColumnName: $('#tableThreeColumnName').val(),
            Condition: $('#tableThreeCondition').val(),
            TextBox: $('#tableThreeTextBox').val(),
            Operator: $('#tableThreeOperator').val()
        }
    ];
```

This is my Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
            traditional: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: domainName + "api/ajaxapi/customfilters",
            data: JSON.stringify(customfiltervalues),
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", getCookie("Token"));
            },
            success: function (response) {}
```

This is my class:

```
public class CustomFilterValues
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    public string Condition { get; set; }

    public string TextBox { get; set; }

    public string Operator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `public List CustomFilters(List customfiltervalues)`? Is it 'List<CustomFilterValues>' or just ArrayList? Also try to send `customfiltervalues` as array, without stringify-ing.

Comment: public List<CustomCaseValues> CustomFilters(List<CustomFilterValues> cutomfiltervalues)

Comment: in your $.ajax call you'll want to add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and if you're expecting JSON on the response add `dataType: "json"` as well.  Other than that, you seem to have the right idea.  Are you getting some type of error or unexpected response?  Is the POST not getting to the controller?  Please provide more details on what the issue is